# How to access arguments between chained promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the below code:

```
vm.testService.getUser(id, name)
.then((resultA) => {
    return vm.testService.getUserInfo(id, name);
})
.then(() => {
    // will process resultA from first .then
});
```

I need to access resultA on the second .then.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the sense of two `then`s when they depend on each other?

Comment: `...getUserInfo(...).then(() => resultA);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to assign the response of the first then to a variable and access that variable in the second then

check the code snippet

```js
let response

vm.testService.getUser(id, name)
  .then((resultA) => {
    response = resultA
    return vm.testService.getUserInfo(id, name);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(response)
    // will process resultA from first .then
  });
```

Comment: I've already thought of assigning it to a higher scope variable. But aside from this, is there any other way?

Comment: Can't answer the question anymore, but you can return an array [resultA, vm.testService.getUserInfo(id, name)] or use Promise.all as well.

Comment: Marking this as an answer since this has less risk on our current implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result of the first callback in the external scope

```
let result;
vm.testService.getUser(id, name)
.then((resultA) => {
    result = resultA;
    return vm.testService.getUserInfo(id, name);
})
.then(() => {
    // 'result' will now equal resultA
});
```